# 'Object' is not convertible to 'T' using Generics in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm getting an error message when trying to use Generics in Swift.  I'm trying to create a function that takes any object that inherits from `Parent`, and modify an `inout` reference which just so happens to be an `Array` of `T: Parent`

```
func myFunction<T: Parent>(data: NSDictionary, inout objects: Array<T>) {
    let myArray = data.valueForKey("the_array") as NSArray

    for object in myArray {
        var addMe: Object = Object()
        //...

        objects.append(addMe) //'Object' is not convertible to 'T'
    }

}
```

I'm passing this into the function higher up the stack.

```
var objects: [Object] = []

myClass.myFunction(data, objects: &objects)
```

Even though `Object` is defined as follows, inheriting from `Parent`

```
class Object: Parent {
    //...
}
```

It gives me an error that it can't convert `Object` to `T`.. although I'm probably mis-interpreting the error message. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: no you're not misinterpreting - an object just isn't a T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to add an `Object` to an array of `T : Parent`. But just because `Object` is a subclass of `Parent` doesn't mean `T` is `Object`. At runtime, `T` could be `Dinosaur`, another subclass of `Parent`, and adding `addMe` to that array would be invalid.

One solution is to initialize `addMe` as `T()`, and optionally cast to `Object`, like so:

```
for object in myArray {
    var addMe = T()

    if let addMe = addMe as? Object {
        // do Objecty stuff here
    }

    //...

    objects.append(addMe)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe Aaron has you on the right track, but note that this probably means a misuse of generics. You more likely meant:

```
func myFunction(data: NSDictionary, inout objects: [Parent]) { ... }
```

There is no reason to say "T, where T is a subclass of Parent." That is just "Parent" in most OOP systems (including Swift).

This is also a very surprising way to handle your return. The normal approach in Swift would be:

```
func myFunction(data: [String : [Object]) -> [Parent] { ... }
```

It is extremely uncommon in Swift to pass an empty array and have the function fill it in. You generally generate the array and return it. Swift has excellent copy-on-write semantics that make this cheap (unlike C++ per-move-semantics, where this pattern is more common).

Wherever possible, try to use Swift Arrays and Dictionaries rather than `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. You will save a lot of complicated `as?` conversions.